# Inner product without transposing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a nxm matrix `A` and nx1 column-vector `B`. I perform an inner product using `transpose(A) * B`. This works fine.

However, I would like to not have to transpose `A` and still get the same result.

Is there a way to get the same result without transposing `A` (possibly with a transpose of `B`?)

My linear algebra skills aren't too great. Hoping to get help from the experts here.

Comment: transpose( transpose(B) * A )

Comment: What do you mean by "inner product"?  Does $A^TB=(B^TA)^T$ help?

Comment: That's it @ACARCHAU. Thanks to you both. Mind posting as an answer so I can accept and close the question?

Answer (score 1):

From a comment, $A^TB=(B^TA)^T$

Comment: It would be better to write this using MathJax (LaTex) as Jonas did in his answer. Regards

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that one could embed LaTeX in StackExchange posts.

Comment: Please see [**MathJax**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [**FAQ**](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq) for further details. The MathJax displaying of math is lovely! Regards